# Как и с помощью чего данный сайт разделяет трафик?

Tags: javascript, php, http-status-code-301

Сегодня я наткнулся на интересный сайт.

если кратко то ПС видит домен `golden-casino.org` который продвигается.
а все остальные видят и переходят на домен `https://vvvvvv.golden-casino.org`

второй домен не индексируется, поэтому при его блокировке просто подклеивается новый `https://2vvvvvv.golden-casino.org`
поэтому как такой переиндексации не происходит.

Подскажите, чем данный сайт пользуется и есть ли в свободном доступе готовые решения?

Comment: Движок сайта -- обычный wordpress, это можете проверить в любом детекторе движков сайта или убедиться вручную, я не вижу чтобы там был какой-то изощрённый клоакинг с подменой кода, хотя судя по тому что сайты-определители плагинов WP пасуют явно используется какая-то система оценки IP-адресов, заголовков и т.п. анализа трафика. Судя по IP вполне обычный VPS-хостер в Литве. Больше особо не выжать: анализаторы трафика не оставят таких следов, так что если только где-то в статьях или на конференциях сами не расскажут чем пользуются.

Comment: `500 Internal Server Error` что-то сдохло там явно.

Comment: на основе юзер агента мб перенаправляется, или нет?